# Assigning actions to QMenu items

Tags: qt

I have created a Qt project in which I'm using a widget and it does not support any menu in the designer's class, so it should be done programmatically. I succeeded in creating the menu and adding the items but I'm struggling in assigning any action for the menu items...

That's what I've done so far:

```
    QMenuBar* menuBar = new QMenuBar();
    QMenu *fileMenu = new QMenu("File");
    menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);
    fileMenu->addAction("Save");
    fileMenu->addAction("Exit");
    QAction* newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
    newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
    newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit"));
    connect(newAct, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::on_action_triggered);

    this->layout()->setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

But no action is triggered when I press The Exit item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addAction` creates `QAction` and returns pointer to it, you dont need to create it explicitly, but when you do you must add item to menu with `addAction`, setting parent is not enough `fileMenu->addAction(newAct);`.